# Flyway migration not execute script: Database 'default' needs migration

Tags: playframework, flyway

In my play framework project, I configured flyway as explained in the guide to this link https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play.

But when I run the application, I see in the log this message:

```
org.flywaydb.play.InvalidDatabaseRevision: Database 'default' needs migration![An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
        at org.flywaydb.play.Flyways.$anonfun$checkState$1(Flyways.scala:174)
        at org.flywaydb.play.Flyways.$anonfun$checkState$1$adapted(Flyways.scala:169)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.flywaydb.play.Flyways.checkState(Flyways.scala:169)
```

The plugin is loaded correctly and the script are in a folder into conf: db/migration/default. How can I solve it?